# What is the best way to reuse some data inside servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am working on code which involves two steps,

Step 1 : In Step 1, We are passing three values (x,y,z) and ID to the servlet as given below,

http://xyz.com/myservlet?x=10&y=20&z=30&ID=555

So as shown above, we are passing three values 10,20,30

Step 2:  Now there is another servlet which want to refer  x,y and z values of ID 555.

I could save x,y,z to file against 555 or  I could use Database to get x,y,z values.

But every time, If I perform Step2 or make call to servlet in step2, Is it good to read data from file every-time.

How can we make it more optimized ?

Comment: Don't read or write files from your servlets unless you have no choice (large amount of data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of doing this is to use the [memcached system](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcache). Some web application servers support this "out-of-the-box", while for others there exist third-party implementations (for example, [jmemcached](http://code.google.com/p/jmemcache-daemon) for Java).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a common static object in memory (Like a `Hashmap`) and put this values inside it and then fetch data from step 2. But be careful about the synchronization between this 2 steps.

Or you can store your values inside the session or application context.